Why does this code not stop to take input?
This is a program which allows only authorized shareholders to attend a meeting, which is given as a file input.
It asks for a name on the terminal and checks if it is in the file. If it is not, it again asks to type the name in the correct format. If the issue persists for the second time, it says that the person is not authorized.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream name_sh;
    name_sh.open("shareholders.dat");
    string keep_sh[1000];
    char varkeep[32];
    name_sh.get(varkeep, 32);
    int counter = 0;
    while(name_sh){
        name_sh.ignore(100, '\n');
        keep_sh[counter] = varkeep;
        counter++;
        name_sh.get(varkeep, 32);
    }


    while(true){
        cout << "Please tell your name or press Q to exit ";
        char input[32];
        cin.get(input, 32);
        if(input[0]=='Q' && input[1]=='\0') break;
        for(int j = 1; j <= 2; j++){
            int i;
            for(i=0; i < counter; i++){
//                char str[32] = keep_sh[i];
                if(input == keep_sh[i]){
                    cout << "You are welcome." << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(i < counter) break;
            else if(j == 1){cout << "Write the official name in the formal way ";cin.get(input, 32);}
            else cout << "Sorry, but you are not allowed." << endl;
        }
        cout << "Next." << endl;
        //break;
    
/*string cc = keep_sh[0];
char cv[32];
cin.get(cv, 32);
cout << (cv == cc);*/

//for(int i=0; i<counter; i++) cout << keep_sh[i] << endl;
//cout << counter;
}

If I uncomment the last break statement, the loop stops while checking if the input is in the keep_sh file or not. But commenting it makes the code run in an infinite loop.
What I am not able to understand is why the terminal is not stopping to take the next input which is exactly on the fifth line after the while loop 'line'?
The commented code lines at the bottom are to show that I have checked that the file input stream is working fine. It is printing the desired output.
Input File contains:
Harry Wellington
Charls Rasso
Tim Pots
Charlie Hammer
Nicolas Jorden
Peter Hann
Tobe Ludwig
Charlie Robert

Each on a separate line.

Don't use arrays to receive input.  Arrays are fixed length (capacity).  Use std::vector, which can grow during runtime.

Test your file opening.  There are many reasons that opening a file can fail.

Are your text lines exactly 32 characters long?  You may want to change your input to std::string name; while (getline(name_sh, name))

What happens if my name is longer than 32 characters?  {Answer:  use std::string instead of char arrays.}

Please see [mre]. Your goal is to demonstrate "the terminal is not stopping for taking the next input ", not to have a program that accomplishes something useful or otherwise makes sense. Everything not needed for this should be removed from your question's example code. In particular, the file should be gone. Just proceed as if your check always fails (or always passes, whichever is more convenient). Then simplify. If the problem occurs after removing lines after the first cin.get(input, 32); then do so. This eliminates distractions and makes your question more applicable to others.

std::istream::get() does not extract the terminating \n when Enter is pressed. You are leaving each \n in the buffer for a subsequent read to extract, thus your input values will have a leading \n that is throwing off your comparisons. Whereas when you are reading lines from the file, you are ignore()'ing the \ns.
There is no good reason to be using char[] arrays in this code.  Both your file input and user input are line-based, and the lines are variable-length, so you should use std::string with std::getline() instead of using chr[] with std::istream::get().
Try something more like this:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<string> keep_sh;
    string varkeep, input;

    ifstream name_sh("shareholders.dat");
    while (getline(name_sh, varkeep) {
        keep_sh.push_back(varkeep);
    }
    name_sh.close();

    do {
        cout << "Please tell your name or press Q to exit: ";
        if (!getline(cin, input)) break;
        if (input == "Q") break;
        for (int j = 1; j <= 2; ++j) {
            if (find(keep_sh.begin(), keep_sh.end(), input) != keep_sh.end()) {
                cout << "You are welcome." << endl;
                break;
            }
            if (j == 1) {
                cout << "Write the official name in the formal way: ";
                getline(cin, input);
                continue;
            }
            cout << "Sorry, but you are not allowed." << endl;
        }
        cout << "Next." << endl;
    }    
    while (true);
}


The simple fix
Every time you call cin.get(input, 32), you have to follow it with a call to cin.ignore.
The following call to cin.ignore reads and discards any characters in the input stream, stopping only when a newline character ('\n') is encountered. The newline is then read and discarded.
cin.get(input, 32);  // input, at most, 31 characters
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

cin.get(input, 32); appears twice in the OP. If you place a call to cin.ignore after each of them, the program will run as expected.
cin.get(input, 32); leaves a newline character in the stream
The reason why this works is because cin.get(input, 32) leaves a newline character in the input stream. Calling cin.ignore inputs (and discards) the newline.
// From the OP:
char input[32];
cin.get(input, 32);  // input, at most, 31 characters

Function cin.get (above) stops inputting characters when either:

31 characters have been input, without encountering a newline ('\n')
a newline is encountered (before inputting 31 characters)

The characters that are successfully input are copied to the array input, and the null character ('\0') is appended after them.
When a newline is encountered, it is left unread, still in the input stream.
In the OP, all subsequent calls to cin.get(input, 32) see the newline, and stop immediately, without reading any characters. The first element of the array input is then set to '\0', so that variable input becomes the empty string.
Two other design flaws
There are issues with using a built-in array to store the names from the shareholder file. A std::set (or possibly, a vector) is a better choice. Using a set has the advantage that lookups are O(log n), and also that a set can be traversed in alphabetical order. Both vectors and sets have the advantage that they can grow to an arbitrary size. They are not limited to the 1000 elements reserved in the OP's built-in array.
The second issue is the use of std::cin.get(str, size) to input C-strings. std::string is a better choice. From both the keyboard and the file, a std::string can be input using std::getline. That way, the program in the OP will be able to handle strings longer than 31 characters.
Neither of these problems, however, is what causes the program to get trapped in an infinite loop, unable to input a shareholder name.
An alternative solution, using a std::set
std::set is one of the containers from the Standard Library.  You can define a set of std::strings like this:
std::set<std::string> shareholders;

This can be made more readable using a type alias.
using shareholder_set = std::set<std::string>;
shareholder_set shareholders;

Two member functions allow you to add new elements to a set.

insert default-constructs a new element in the set, and then copies the argument of insert to the new element. Given string s, for instance, shareholders.insert(s) constructs a new element in the set, and then copies s into that element.

emplace constructs a new element in-place, using the arguments of emplace as the arguments of the constructor. Given strings s, for instance, shareholders.emplace(std::move(s)) invokes the move constructor of class string to construct the new element of the set. Emplace is generally more efficient than insert, because it avoids the copy step.


Two member functions allow you to check whether a given string is a member of a set.

count was used prior to C++20. Given string s, for instance, shareholders.count(s) returns 0 when s is not in the set, and 1 when it is. By checking the count, therefore, you can determine if s is in the set.

contains, which was added in C++20, is much simpler. It returns either true or false, depending whether its argument in the the set. Given string s, for example, if (shareholders.contains(s)) { ... } is the most natural way to check whether s is in the set.


Range-based for loops work with std::set
You can iterate over the elements of a set using a range-based for loop.
Here is an example that creates the file shareholders.dat, and copies the shareholders from a set into it.
// All of the programs below share this using declaration.

using shareholder_set = std::set<std::string>;

void write_file(
    std::string const& file_name, 
    shareholder_set const& shareholders)
{
    std::ofstream ofs{ file_name };
    for (auto const& s : shareholders) {  // for each string `s` in `shareholders`
        ofs << s << '\n';
    }
    ofs.close();
}

The next example uses a range-based for loop to display a list of shareholders.
void display(shareholder_set const& shareholders) {
    std::cout <<
        "============================\n"
        " Shareholders in Attendance \n"
        "============================\n\n";
    int n{};
    for (auto const& s : shareholders) {
        std::cout << ++n << ". " << s << '\n';
    }
    std::cout.put('\n');
}

Reading a file into a set
The following function reads the file shareholders.dat into a set. The set is created as "local" variable, and then returned (using NRVO).
The function uses contains to check whether a name appears more than once in the file.
Note that std::getline reads an entire line into a string. It stops when it encounters a newline. Unlike cin.get(input, 32), it does not leave the newline in the stream. It reads, and discards, the newline, without storing it in the string.
Function tbx::getln_yes_no is a helper from my toolbox. It asks the user a yes-or-no question, and returns true or false, respectively, for "yes" and "no."
shareholder_set read_file(std::string const& file_name) {
    shareholder_set shareholders;
    std::ifstream ifs{ file_name };
    if (!ifs.is_open()) {
        return shareholders;
    }
    bool contains_duplicate{ false };
    std::string s;
    while (std::getline(ifs, s)) {
        if (shareholders.contains(s)) {
            contains_duplicate = true;
            std::cerr << "Skipping duplicate name:"
                << "\n  Shareholder file: " << std::quoted(file_name)
                << "\n  Duplicate name: " << std::quoted(s)
                << "\n\n";
        }
        else {
            shareholders.emplace(std::move(s));
        }
    }
    ifs.close();
    if (contains_duplicate &&
        tbx::getln_yes_no("Do you want to erase the duplicates from the file? ")) {
        write_file(file_name, shareholders);
    }
    return shareholders;
}

A dedicated function for inputting shareholder names
Function get_shareholder_name (below) prompts the user to enter a shareholder name, and then inputs one of two things:

a blank line (which indicates "quit")
a single shareholder name (which has been found in the set)

Any other entry is rejected, and causes the function to ask again.
Function tbx::trim_whitespace is another function from my toolbox.
std::string get_shareholder_name(shareholder_set const& shareholders)
{
    std::string s;
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << "Shareholder: ";
        if (!std::getline(std::cin, s)) {
            throw std::runtime_error{ "get_shareholder_name: `std::getline` failed." };
        }
        std::cout.put('\n');
        s = tbx::trim_whitespace(s);
        if (s.empty() || shareholders.contains(s)) {
            break;
        }
        std::cout << "  Name not found. Please reenter.\n\n";
    }
    return s;
}

Run a loop to input all shareholders at the meeting
Given function get_shareholder_name (above), it is trivial to run a loop, and input the names of all shareholders at a meeting. The function below returns the names in a set.
Any name that is entered more that once is flagged as a duplicate.
shareholder_set get_shareholders(shareholder_set const& shareholders) {
    std::cout <<
        "=====================\n"
        " Shareholder Meeting \n"
        "=====================\n"
        "\nEnter the names of shareholders in attendance."
        "\nPress Enter to quit."
        "\n\n";
    shareholder_set shareholders_in_attendance;
    std::string s;
    while (!(s = get_shareholder_name(shareholders)).empty()) {
        if (shareholders_in_attendance.contains(s)) {
            std::cout << "  " << std::quoted(s) << " has already been entered.\n\n";
        }
        else {
            shareholders_in_attendance.emplace(std::move(s));
        }
    }
    return shareholders_in_attendance;
}

Top-down design of function main
Bottom-up might a better way to describe this, because all the child functions were developed above. Nevertheless, I think of function main (below) as a top-down function.
int main() {
    std::string const file_name{ "shareholders.dat" };
    auto const shareholders{ read_file(file_name) };
    if (shareholders.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Error: could not read file " 
            << std::quoted(file_name) << "\n\n";
    }
    else {
        auto const shareholders_in_attendance{ 
            get_shareholders(shareholders)
        };
        display(shareholders_in_attendance);
    }
}

Output from a sample run
=====================
 Shareholder Meeting
=====================

Enter the names of shareholders in attendance.
Press Enter to quit.

Shareholder: Harry Wellington

Shareholder: Harry

  Name not found. Please reenter.

Shareholder: Harry Wellington

  "Harry Wellington" has already been entered.

Shareholder: Charls Rasso

Shareholder: Tim Pots

Shareholder: Charlie Hammer

Shareholder: Charlie Robert

Shareholder:

============================
 Shareholders in Attendance
============================

1. Charlie Hammer
2. Charlie Robert
3. Charls Rasso
4. Harry Wellington
5. Tim Pots

Complete source code
// main.cpp
#include <algorithm>    // transform
#include <cctype>       // toupper
#include <fstream>      // ifstream, ofstream
#include <iomanip>      // quoted
#include <iostream>     // cin, cout, cerr
#include <set>          // set
#include <stdexcept>    // runtime_error
#include <string>       // getline, string
#include <string_view>  // find_first_not_of, find_last_not_of, npos, string_view
#include <utility>      // move

namespace tbx
{
    // A few functions from my toolbox:
    //==================================================================
    // trim_whitespace
    //==================================================================
    std::string_view trim_whitespace_view(std::string_view sv) noexcept
    {
        // Trim leading and trailing whitespace from string_view `sv`.
        enum : std::string_view::size_type { zero, one };
        auto const first{ sv.find_first_not_of(" \f\n\r\t\v") };
        if (first == std::string_view::npos)
            return sv.substr(zero, zero);
        auto const last{ sv.find_last_not_of(" \f\n\r\t\v") };
        return sv.substr(first, (last - first + one));
    }
    inline std::string trim_whitespace(std::string const& s) {
        return std::string{ trim_whitespace_view(s) };
    }
    //==================================================================
    // to_upper_in_place
    //==================================================================
    inline char to_upper(unsigned char const c) noexcept {
        return static_cast<char>(std::toupper(c));
    }
    inline void to_upper_in_place(std::string& s) noexcept {
        std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
            [](unsigned char const c) { return tbx::to_upper(c); }
        );
    }
    //==================================================================
    // getln_yes_no
    //==================================================================
    bool getln_yes_no(
        std::string const prompt,
        std::istream& ist = std::cin,
        std::ostream& ost = std::cout)
    {
        std::string s;
        for (;;) {
            ost << prompt;
            if (!std::getline(ist, s))
                throw std::runtime_error("getln_yes_no: `std::getline` failed.");
            to_upper_in_place(s);
            auto const sv{ trim_whitespace_view(s) };
            if (sv == "Y" || sv == "YES")
                return true;
            if (sv == "N" || sv == "NO")
                return false;
            ost << "Invalid entry. Please reenter.\n\n";
        }
        std::unreachable();
    }
}

//======================================================================
// Shareholder Application
//======================================================================

using shareholder_set = std::set<std::string>;

//======================================================================
// write_file
//======================================================================
void write_file(
    std::string const& file_name, 
    shareholder_set const& shareholders)
{
    std::ofstream ofs{ file_name };
    for (auto const& s : shareholders) {
        ofs << s << '\n';
    }
    ofs.close();
}
//======================================================================
// read_file
//======================================================================
shareholder_set read_file(std::string const& file_name) {
    shareholder_set shareholders;
    std::ifstream ifs{ file_name };
    if (!ifs.is_open()) {
        return shareholders;
    }
    bool contains_duplicate{ false };
    std::string s;
    while (std::getline(ifs, s)) {
        if (shareholders.contains(s)) {
            contains_duplicate = true;
            std::cerr << "Skipping duplicate name:"
                << "\n  Shareholder file: " << std::quoted(file_name)
                << "\n  Duplicate name: " << std::quoted(s)
                << "\n\n";
        }
        else {
            shareholders.emplace(std::move(s));
        }
    }
    ifs.close();
    if (contains_duplicate &&
        tbx::getln_yes_no("Do you want to erase the duplicates from the file? ")) {
        write_file(file_name, shareholders);
    }
    return shareholders;
}
//======================================================================
// get_shareholder_name
//======================================================================
std::string get_shareholder_name(shareholder_set const& shareholders)
{
    std::string s;
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << "Shareholder: ";
        if (!std::getline(std::cin, s)) {
            throw std::runtime_error{ "get_shareholder_name: `std::getline` failed." };
        }
        std::cout.put('\n');
        s = tbx::trim_whitespace(s);
        if (s.empty() || shareholders.contains(s)) {
            break;
        }
        std::cout << "  Name not found. Please reenter.\n\n";
    }
    return s;
}
//======================================================================
// get_shareholders
//======================================================================
shareholder_set get_shareholders(shareholder_set const& shareholders) {
    std::cout <<
        "=====================\n"
        " Shareholder Meeting \n"
        "=====================\n"
        "\nEnter the names of shareholders in attendance."
        "\nPress Enter to quit."
        "\n\n";
    shareholder_set shareholders_in_attendance;
    std::string s;
    while (!(s = get_shareholder_name(shareholders)).empty()) {
        if (shareholders_in_attendance.contains(s)) {
            std::cout << "  " << std::quoted(s) << " has already been entered.\n\n";
        }
        else {
            shareholders_in_attendance.emplace(std::move(s));
        }
    }
    return shareholders_in_attendance;
}
//======================================================================
// display
//======================================================================
void display(shareholder_set const& shareholders) {
    std::cout <<
        "============================\n"
        " Shareholders in Attendance \n"
        "============================\n\n";
    int n{};
    for (auto const& s : shareholders) {
        std::cout << ++n << ". " << s << '\n';
    }
    std::cout.put('\n');
}
//======================================================================
// main
//======================================================================
int main() {
    std::string const file_name{ "shareholders.dat" };
    auto const shareholders{ read_file(file_name) };
    if (shareholders.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Error: could not read file " 
            << std::quoted(file_name) << "\n\n";
    }
    else {
        auto const shareholders_in_attendance{ 
            get_shareholders(shareholders)
        };
        display(shareholders_in_attendance);
    }
}
// end file: main.cpp

